# Getting error in microsoft api while using SSO feature in teams tab app with multi teanant

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

Getting error in microsoft api while using SSO feature in teams tab app with multi teanant where sso feature is implement using teams toolkit add feature section by using  **SSO enabled Tab**

I want to implement sso feature over teams tab app, so I used to team toolkit to implement the feature, The sso is working with my teant microsoft account but not working with other teanant account

Error Detail mention below:-

```
{error: "invalid_resource",…}
correlation_id: "4c3b68b7-e486-4a0b-9f6b-18daca87d36a"
error: "invalid_resource"
error_codes: [500011]
0: 500011
error_description: "AADSTS500011: The resource principal named api://myconnectprodc5820ctab.z10.web.core.windows.net/dc64f450-283f-4d88-88ca-2746d5898f15 was not found in the tenant named Contoso. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: 43460303-4cfb-4426-af97-d82fff0e6b00\r\nCorrelation ID: 4c3b68b7-e486-4a0b-9f6b-18daca87d36a\r\nTimestamp: 2023-05-30 11:55:44Z"
error_uri: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=500011"
timestamp: "2023-05-30 11:55:44Z"
trace_id: "43460303-4cfb-4426-af97-d82fff0e6b00"
===============================================================================================
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/5ec8afbc-af51-44e6-87dc-d90f5b953f77/oauth2/v2.0/token 400 (Bad Request)
(anonymous) @ msal-browser.min-8cecb01.js:1
(anonymous) @ msal-browser

==============================================================================================
payload details:

client_id:

5e3ce6c0-2b1f-4285-8d4b-75ee78787346

scope:

api://myconnectprodc5820ctab.z10.web.core.windows.net/dc64f450-283f-4d88-88ca-2746d5898f15/.default openid profile offline_access

grant_type:

refresh_token

client_info:

1

x-client-SKU:

msal.js.browser

x-client-VER:

2.19.0

x-client-OS:

 

x-client-CPU:

 

x-ms-lib-capability:

retry-after, h429

x-client-current-telemetry:

5|61,0,,,|,

x-client-last-telemetry:

5|0|61,7f9cc446-4a2e-45ac-87ef-55257d77f401|invalid_resource|1,0

client-request-id:

f92f2e44-60d3-4a82-9655-05e0347d369e

refresh_token:

0.AVAAvK_IXlGv5kSH3NkPW5U_d8DmPF4fK4VCjUt17nh4c0Z_AJ8.AgABAAEAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrAgDs_wUA9P9L-NHcSdt1rFT1kQ5tIqlFsPhVRFKRoqeH9b2WN1RuAh985KMjgz7Y_tXk4IpwCSNB2nZBo9_iYCqAiUVPxtnrMYobUc_L-5uzAt64bGTOVbDdGCyuYS3O9r-0ZwUzvo8VkfqSqyyKInSxNMcvSjZlGSUjGkDGDRLsVvI6ys7g8__leM8P_agpEeEmgvEuPp-LA8sKanopWIcEmy8CchIwsWv7FtwcqLJppVfv7EP40avv6dE1Djg26HuSewbt81K8iBdNwXm4lgBpcNDlhxRATuoOJoLeI03D7JqueeCmTzDM8SYw0AGamCBwpA-v-DqdQG5Nn_e09yzFe61t2GsQGkF9c0iZ2YyA8UO5l3rHWTfyBoDaKgKwKM54_7SYBF2I-v-GXaw0SLEeR3v7A3fuMsT2meMofz7MCgtYhuefEpDQWnkS9pPT1ZsRWYhKAAzUQaXXafoEM1VQwbiueHxRojDF8g0EqPCIbmzYKoP-nsGFm_fDsOonYc7s8UmaImmMfn_S-gzSAiRQpkbTnNxY6jjSUMBrYakjOQ94oh2vcSAGhHTih2IxmAUbrcZve4qxF25zN8xZwcoK21oM9vY6AZBcmGsEtUQ8y1nGkOT_Reg6CZgZbb3NxS-qQ-kuGNPrFavhBDIqQQpfZ8kqZs4AlJnqP2MWn4N9moek0hECPwRNEXulZroDc7CMnsHw_GiKl05CAGOlywny2IhMIp1T8hhzrD5JRzRo117clyeHwtNEf37OM1oMrffBLvL7RZ9YN18eAE5605qHoMGN9fldyy4OBnZfr9vgTzwy7sVRXpv7xzmPzh9XHq4LYIQtc5yi8DthHDTLbVp64V1O6gQo1JOEufbJ0NMrmuzl2HpYzQ91sr1APKBZ2Z7bnh62JZqBMl7V_2GSfhhGY01l2IRpy3VWUcs7XRB5w_KvEe4VhZXzK67ltg-wF0k2Bj8l4JzkfJmgUOVcCF-_7hYdfo6sVgkAeZpE1WDsJJ9esjhxbNEY1CzlxuTcd1PMXe5vt68LLvW5ebj0JR6WsH8ZfHgqRIgUG-jTkBYILPauZhU

X-AnchorMailbox:

Oid:83675ef5-a7ce-411e-912f-117d9bbca371@5ec8afbc-af51-44e6-87dc-d90f5b953f77
```

Comment: You can share the detailed error messages for your problem

Comment: Could you please share the error which you are getting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Refer to error detail , Updated the quetion

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [wiki](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/wiki/Multi-tenancy-Support-for-Azure-AD-app) to use Azure CDN for multi-tenant apps.
For Tab app, you need to:

1. Provision your app first.
2. Find your frontend domain in `.fx/states/state.{env}.json`(for v4.x of Teams Toolkit) or in `env/.env.{env}` (for v5.x of Teams Toolkit)
3. Provision your Azure CDN. (You can skip this step if you have an Custom Domain.)
4. Update frontend info in `templates\azure\provision\azureStorageTab.bicep`(for v4.x of Teams Toolkit) or `infra/azure.bicep`(for v5.x of Teams Toolkit)
5. Update `aad.manifest.json` and set value of `signInAudience` to `AzureADMultipleOrgs`
6. Open `.fx/configs/azure.parameter.${env}.json`(for v4.x of Teams Toolkit) or `infra/azure.parameter.json`(for v5.x of Teams Toolkit) and set value of `m365TenantId` to "common"
7. Provision and Deploy the app again
   And then your app should work as multi-tenant app.